# Usando várias páginas html com o mesmo controller AngularJS + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net, rotas

Usando as rotas com o AngularJS, Ao entrar na página Autor.html com a rota `/Autor`, é listado todos autores cadastrados em uma tabela onde é criado um link para a edição de cada autor, conforme essa linha de código `<a ng-click="setAutor(autor)" ng-href="#!/Autor/Editar/{{autor.ID}}">`, ao clicar no editar de um autor é diparado a rota `/Autor/Editar/:id`, que será aberto a página html `Editar.html`, ambas páginas usam o mesmo controller `autorController`, só que quando é aberto minha página `Editar.html` o objeto model `autor.Nome` não vem preenchido, o controller de uma página para outra é "resetado" o seu $scope?

Como eu faço para passar esse objeto de uma página a outra usando o mesmo controller?

> App.js

```js
(function () {
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", { controller: "homeController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Home/Home.html" })
        .when("/Livro", { controller: "livroController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Livro/Livro.html" })
        .when("/Autor", { controller: "autorController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Autor/Autor.html" })
        .when("/Autor/Editar/:id", { controller: "autorController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Autor/Editar.html" })
        .when("/Editora", { controller: "editoraController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Editora/Editora.html" })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

});
}());
```

> autorController.js

```js
(function () {
    angular.module("app").controller("autorController", function ($scope, $http) {
      
        $scope.getAll = function() {
            $http.get("/api/AutorAPI")
            .then(function(data) {
                $scope.autores = data.data;
            });
        }

        $scope.setAutor = function(autor) {
            $scope.autor = autor;
        }
    });
}());
```

> Autor.html

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="autorController">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>  </th>
                <th> ID </th>
                <th> Nome </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="autor in autores">
            <tr>
                <th> 
                    <a ng-click="setAutor(autor)" ng-href="#!/Autor/Editar/{{autor.ID}}">
                </th>
                <th> {{autor.ID}} </th>
                <th> {{autor.Nome}} </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

> Editar.html

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="autorController">
    <label class="label-control"> Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-Model="autor.Nome"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, suas variáveis  $autor e $autores estão incorretas. Declara-se uma variável no AngularJS usando `$scope` de início. Tente utilizar $scope.autor e $scope.autores.
Se possível faça um JSFiddle ou Plunker de exemplo. Obviamente sua chamada pra API não irá funcionar, você pode trocar o endereço pelo deste site aqui que hosteia um json de graça: http://myjson.com/

Comment: @Jackson, corrigi onde disse que estava errado, eu testei assim com o scope também, mas não deu certo, é que acabei realizando varios teste e quando reencrevi o código para postar aqui esqueci de colocar $scope. Mesmo assim o meu problema persiste.